# Dart March 30 days

Tags: dart

Small question :

I calculate the number of days in a given month like so :

```
new DateTime(2018, month+1, 1).difference(new DateTime(2018,month,1)).inDays
```

All is working fine, `februari` gives me `28` days, all months are correctly `30/31` days except for `March`, which gives me `30` days instead of `31`.

Has anyone seen this before and perhaps an explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably DST.  Stupid DST.  We need to get rid of DST.  Edit: probably if you use UTC instead of local timezone, it'd work right.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because of daylight-saving, try **new DateTime.utc()**, the below code outputs the correct values

```
for(int month = 1; month < 13; month++) {

  int daysInMonth = new DateTime.utc(2018, month+1,1).difference(new DateTime.utc(2018,month,1)).inDays;

  print(daysInMonth);
}
```

"When dealing with dates or historic events prefer to use UTC DateTimes, since they are unaffected by daylight-saving changes and are unaffected by the local timezone."

Comment: Quote them instead of posting a link.